# Inserting data into mysql with PHP after security patching fails

Tags: php, mysql, debian

MySQL is 5.5.55
PHP is 5.4.45-0+deb7u8

My web server with local database had been working fine for over a year, but after running an unattended security update, I can't add data to tables;

```
$commandString = "LOAD DATA INFILE '/dir/dir/dir/$name' INTO TABLE tableName FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' IGNORE 2 LINES (@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,dateTimeOrigination,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,callingPartyNumber,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,originalCalledPartyNumber,finalCalledPartyNumber,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,pkid,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,duration,origDeviceName,destDeviceName,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy)";

mysqli_query($db_conn,$commandString);
```

If I restore the server back before patching, it works fine again.  I'm not receiving any errors for passwords or a failure to connect with;

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

And I'm not finding any errors in /var/log/syslog.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to review the PHP log, not syslog. Also, a mysql error will not display on these log, you need to use mysqli_error();

Comment: Hi, Sakura.  This does not appear to be a PHP issue, mysqli is connecting fine, and if I change the password for the account used to connect to mysql, it bombs out and complains that the credentials are incorrect.

Comment: But, also, aftr doing mysqli_query() you can use mysqli_error() to check any error returned from dbms.

Comment: Hi Sakura.  Thank you!  That totally worked.  The error I was getting was "The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement", which meant that I needed to change "LOAD DATA INFILE" to "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE".  Thank you very much for your help.  I just wish I knew what changed in the patching.